# Nearby.MESSAGES_API Deprecated

Tags: java, android

How can I change this method that already appears as deprecated to the one that should be used, since I do not find documentation. Thank you

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
                    .build();
```

Comment: android studio notifies me that Nearby.MESSAGES_API is deprecated, can be used or is now implemented in another way.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client) it states that `GoogleApiClient` is deprecated:

> However, the newer `GoogleApi` interface and its implementations are
>   easier to use and are the preferred way to access Play services APIs.
>   See [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).

You can refer to the [Nearby Messagges API docs](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started) for a tutorial on how to get started